# How to create responsive square

Tags: css

I trying to create a responsive square, but I cannot understand how to build it.
Attempt:

HTML

```
<div id='square'></div>
```

My css:

```
#square{
width: 20%;
height:20%;
}
```

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "responsive"? 2) You misspelled "square" in the CSS.

Comment: sorry this mistake only here, in my code I haven't it.

Comment: It *could* be that your problem (which I have yet to understand) is caused by a typo in your code that we don't see since you didn't copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:
    #square{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 20% 20% 0;
    }